# MatchMode ANYWHERE and EXACT

Tags: c#

http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html

MatchMode   ANYWHERE
          Match the pattern anywhere in the string

MatchMode   EXACT
          Match the entire string to the pattern

where is the difference. In real examples i can't find difference or my examples are not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANYWHERE should generate a LIKE pattern of the form '%yoursearchtext%', EXACT should simply generate the pattern 'yoursearchtext'.  ANYWHERE will match 'ello' in 'Hello world', EXACT shouldn't.

Comment: bonus question. :)  which one performs better?